# What's this language token/keyword/thingy mean?

Tags: programming-languages, language-features

At the following URL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICacheVisitor is the following code chunk:

```
boolean visitDevice(in string deviceID, in nsICacheDeviceInfo deviceInfo);
```

I thought I was dealing with c++, but "in" is not a c++ keyword according to c++ keyword lists i looked up, nor is it a java keyword. So what's it there for and what's it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the parameter is an input parameter, meaning that it will be used but not modified by the function.

The opposite of an `in` parameter is an `out` parameter, which means that the parameter is going to be modified, but not explicitly returned. If you were to use an `out` parameter after a method that uses it, the value is going to (potentially) be different.

As nos points out in the comment, the page you linked to is describing a `.idl`, or Interface definition language, file. I'm not familiar with the IDL that Mozilla uses (but if you want to learn more, you [can read about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPIDL)), but I am somewhat familiar with the Object Management Group's IDL, which says that `in` parameters are call-by-value, `out` parameters are call-by-result, and `inout` parameters are call-by-value/result.

Comment: I thought it might mean that, but the syntax confused me. is "in" a keyword of some language or have they written the documentation using some sort of pseudocode standard?

Comment: As you'll see on that page, it is the documentation for an .idl file, not a C/C++ file. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPIDL

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The OMG IDL is where I've seen in and out (along with inout) before.

Answer (score 3):

The language is Mozilla's Interface Description Language (XPIDL).
The keyword "in" is described here: [here](http://www.mozilla.org/scriptable/xpidl/idl-authors-guide/rules.html#methods-and-attrs)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen frameworks/SDKs for C/C++ that define macros to indicate whether a parameter is for input, output or both. I'm guessing that that's what's going on in your example.

For example, the Windows DDK does this for `IN` `OUT` and `INOUT` (if I remember right).  When compiling these macros are defined to nothing, they have the potential to be defined to something useful for other tools (like an IDL compiler or a static analysis tool).  I;m not sure if they still use these macros in the more recent DDKs.

Microsoft has taken this idea to an extreme with the SAL macros that give a very fine level of control over what behavior is expected for a parameter.